# c++ undefined reference to member function defined outside of header file

Tags: c++, class, g++, undefined-reference, member-functions

I am under the impression that you are allowed to define member functions of a class in one file and then use those functions in another file, as long as both files are compiled and sent to the linker. However, doing this gives me an undefined reference error if I use g++ (4.6.4). Interestingly, using the intel compiler (icpc 11.0) does not give an error and everything works. Is there some flag I can set in g++ to make this work, or is the intel compiler letting me get away with something I shouldn't be doing? Here is some code that reproduces my problem:

class.h:

```
#ifndef _H
#define _H

typedef class
{
    public:
            int a;
            int b;

            void set(int x, int y);
            int add(void);
} Test;

#endif
```

class.cpp:

```
#include "class.h"

void Test::set(int x, int y)
{
    a = x;
    b = y;
}

int Test::add(void)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "class.h"

int main(void)
{
    Test n;
    n.set(3, 4);
    printf("%d\n", n.add());

    return 0;
}
```

To compile, I do:

```
$ g++ class.cpp main.cpp -o test 
/tmp/ccRxOI40.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `Test::set(int, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `Test::add()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: No need for the `typedef`, just do `class Test {};`.

Comment: `_H` is reserved for the implementation, chose a [legal identifier.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797)

Comment: @dyp The extra flags for g++ didn't make a difference (but I had to change `-std=c++11` to `-std=c++0x`). I think that what I did with `g++ class.cpp main.cpp` was fine, but just in case I tried `g++ -c class.cpp -o class.o` and `g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o` and finally `g++ class.o main.o -o test` and got the same error

Comment: Oops, I misread. I'm sorry. The extra flags `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` tell the compiler to produce more warnings, which can reveal some bugs. The `-std=...` is to be more portable, the default is `gnu++98` IIRC, some extension to C++98.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, this is strange, but what happened is that this construct:

```
typedef class
{
    public:
            int a;
            int b;

            void set(int x, int y);
            int add(void);
} Test;
```

while legal is not being treated semantically the same by the compiler as:

```
class Test
{
    public:
            int a;
            int b;

            void set(int x, int y);
            int add(void);
};
```

The `typedef` version makes your methods `static` to the file, as indicated in the `nm` output:

```
$ nm class.o
0000000000000024 t _ZN4Test3addEv
0000000000000000 t _ZN4Test3setEii
                 U __gxx_personality_v0
```

While the `class Test` version makes them proper methods:

```
$ nm class2.o
0000000000000024 T _ZN4Test3addEv
0000000000000000 T _ZN4Test3setEii
                 U __gxx_personality_v0
```

This is why the linker failed to find the symbols.

> **Edit:** As to why this is happening, it seems to be due to an issue with interpreting how the Standard specifies the treatment of the `typedef` name as a *class-name*. Newer compilers do not seem to exhibit the same issue. The problem reported in this question was reproduced with g++ 4.4.7.

If you move the code in your `class.cpp` file into `main.cpp` and only compile `main.cpp`, things will work. Alternatively, you can inline the method definitions into `class.h`.

If you want to leave them as separate translation units, you need to change the `class.h` file so that your class is defined using the `class Test` way instead of using the `typedef` on the anonymous class.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, do you know why this happened? I thought the two versions would be equivalent.

Comment: Because you declared an anonymous class. Since the class doesn't really have a name, the C++ compiler figures it would be a violation to try to resolve a global symbol related to a method for that class. So, it made your methods file local. [Here's a related question.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/612328/315052).

Comment: The name in introduced by `typedef` is  **a** *class-name**, while the Standard requires each member functions defined outside the class to use "its *class-name*" (singular).  Not "one of its class-names" (plural), which would include ones created by `typedef`.  Seems like the Standard could use some clarification on that.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thanks, so I should change the "not kosher" wording to something indicating the proper way to deal with it is ambiguous?

Comment: But what about 7.1.3/9? "If the typedef declaration defines an unnamed class (or enum), the first _typedef-name_ declared by the declaration to be that class type (or enum type) is used to denote the class type (or enum type) for linkage purposes only (3.5)."  And 3.5 specifically says that such classes and their members have external linkage.

Comment: @aschepler: So you think this is a GCC bug?

Comment: If this is a g++ bug, then it's fixed in g++4.10 Because the OP's example works in my g++4.10, no linker error.

Comment: clang does not seem to have a problem with the `typedef` on anonymous struct either.